# Https request to update data in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have previously asked questions on the matter and still a bit stuck. What I am trying to solve is the following:
- Whenever a document gets added, it needs to be updated some time after (2 hours)

How I am currently solving it is:
- I create a timestamp on creation of the document with onCreate
- I append the document to an array
- I have another https function that triggers every 1 minute (as a cron job) which checks the items in the array and compares the current timestamp with the timestamp of the document (which is a variable in the database)

The code which I have is the following:

```
   const array = []

   export const onTimerCreate = functions.firestore
   .document(`Message/{UserId}/{ChatRoomId}/{UserId_1}`)
   .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
     const timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds
     array.push(snapshot)
     return snapshot.ref.update({ creationTime: timestamp})

   })

   export const testDelay = functions.https.onRequest((request,               response) => {
     const timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds
     array.forEach( snapshot => {
       const data = snapshot.data()
       const time = data.creationTime
       const delay = (data.delay) / 1000
       const actualTime = time + delay
       console.log(array)
       if (actualTime > timestamp) {
         return snapshot.ref.update({ delay : 0})
       }
     })
   })
```

However, the problem is right now the request just times out after 60 seconds. What I think is happening is that I am not appending the document properly, as the array I am adding things into with the first function isn't holding data. However I am unsure how to fix this. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your testDelay function will always time out because it never sends a response to the client.  [According to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().

If you don't call one of those methods on the response object, Cloud Functions will not terminate your function, and it will time out.

Note that if you perform async work (such as document updates) in an HTTP type function, you must send the response only after all the promises from those async operations are resolved.

Comment: Are the elements being updates correctly to the array though? Even if its from two different functions? Like when a document is created does it get uploaded to the array and then the array is read from the http function through the snapshot?

Comment: That's something you would be able to tell from looking at the document, right?

Comment: I added this to the if statement : `response.send(snapshot.ref.update({ delay : 0}))` and i put an else statement saying `response.end()`. Still not working though